# Is what Lowe's Home Improvement online does legal? Can stores list items as in inventory when they are already sold to be installed?

Tags: united-states, internet, breach-of-contract

I bought a dishwasher on Lowe's Home Improvement website. The site said it would be available for pickup the next day at my local store. I get a confirmation email for my order in a few minutes and a repeat statement it would be available the next day.
The next day I get an email saying my dishwasher has arrived at my local store, come pick it up. I show up to get it, and customer service says, it must be in the back, I'll be right back with it.
40 minutes later, the Assistant General Manager, says they are still looking, but cant find it. They'll keep looking and call me when they find it. 3 HOURS LATER and no call...

Now get this - the store HAS 2 of the model I bought in inventory on their computer, and the AGM admitted their were 2 sitting in the back with other people's names on them to be installed in their homes sometime, but he didn't give me one of those, EVEN THOUGH LOWE'S SENT ME AN EMAIL TO COME PICK IT YESTERDAY!

My guess is Lowe's Home Improvement online sales operation's computerized system didn't figure out they actually need to send one to my store since the store shows two in stock. The ASM said he'll check today and if one of the two dishwashers in the store aren't to be installed in the next two weeks, he'll "let me have one of those". Even though I was told to come pick it up yesterday!!!

Aside from being a bad business practice, telling a customer to come pick up his purchase (by email) and then not delivering it when he shows up at the store... is this even legal?

Especially when he has 2 sitting in the store and continues to show them on his store's inventory?

I had already pulled my old dishwasher out and expected to install the new one yesterday as promised by the Lowe's Home Improvement website and the email that "Your dishwasher has arrived." Now I have a slowly dripping waterline in my kitchen, the kitchen is all apart awaiting the install, and I am not a happy camper.

Comments welcome

Comment: Apparently, they had wrong data in their inventory system (who knows why, maybe the items where stolen). These things can happen and it doesn't appear that they did that on purpose. You might ask them for reimursement for the delay they cause in the delivery, but not much more.

Comment: Did you get that they sent me an email that my dishwasher had come in and to come and pick it up?  Wouldn't an inventory mistake be corrected when they learn of it?

Comment: Turns out that they didn't remove 2 dishwashers from their computer inventory that had been purchased awaiting Lowe's installation that they had set aside in a different area in the back. After I complained to corporate, they let me pickup my dishwasher the next day (from the two they had in stock, but set aside for installs, I presume). Goofy business practice - still wonder if that's legal. Perhaps a way to get people in the store? Advertise the low-priced item on the web, then upsell when people come in to buy?

Comment: See the linked question. Whether it's legal really boils down to the question whether they did that on purpose or not. If it was just a mistake, they might be liable and owe you some compensation, but that's far from being a crime.